# Como obter valor de ID com jquery dentro de um loop php?

Tags: php, jquery

Como posso obter um id dinâmico com jquery dentro de um looping while php?
A ação funciona corretamente, quando inspeciono o elemento ele lista na DOM certinho, mostrando um id diferente a cada [iteração] no looping;

Porém ao tentar recuperar o valor do ID com jquery, a ação lista apenas o primeiro ID [ Em todas as iterações ].

```html
<?php while($rowCount = $listar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td id="<?= $rowCount['id']; ?>" class="getId"></td>
  <tr>
<?php } ?>


//jquery
$(".getId").on('click', function(){
  let teste = $(".getId").attr('id');    
  console.log(teste);
});
```

Comment: Não use ID, id é único, use classe. Ou seja, insira então na sua classe um nome comum e use também um data-id="" com o id que você quer passar, dessa forma, você vai conseguir recuperar pelo jquery.

Comment: <td data-id="<?= $rowCount['id']; ?>" class="getId"></td>

Comment: Sim, obrigado @Sr. André Baill [ editado ];
Add a classe e troquei id por data-id <td data-id="<?= $rowCount['id']; ?>" class="getId"></td>.

Porém ao recuperar com jquery permanece o problema, me parece ser um erro de lógica simples, porém fora do meu alcance.

Ao clicar em qualquer ítem no looping, continua a identificar apenas o ID da primeira iteração.

No inspect tudo 100%;

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('id')`;. Vc quer pegar o id do elemento clicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que ao fazer `$(".getId").attr('id')` você não está informando corretamente qual elemento com a classe `.getId` você quer selecionar. Se usar apenas `.getId`, o jQuery vai selecionar apenas o primeiro elemento na página que tiver essa classe.

Já que você quer pegar o valor do atributo `id` do próprio elemento que disparou o evento `click`, use o `this`.

```
let teste = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Entendido! Obrigado amigo, deu certo;  É apenas para armazenar um identificador do post para realizar as requisições via ajax;
Não te favoritei por ter reputação insuficiente, mas valeu!!!

Comment: De nada! Vc pode marcar a resposta com ✔️. Não precisa de reputação. Obg!